# I am facing error in starting new Activity inside tabview

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabs

In my application, I am showing List inside the Tabview in one tab, whenever I am trying to start a new activity on onclick a list view touch event. I want to start a new activity in webview.

```
showNewsListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
 showNewsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
            Log.v("status ","tab on   position"+position);
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(BizTab.this, MainView.class);
           startActivity(myIntent);

          }
          });

 getUrlData(baseUrl);

 }
```

if I run this much code app is crashing so I just find its solution that I should start a new activity asynchronously so now, I m doing this:

```
    showNewsListView.setAdapter(listAdapter); 
    showNewsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) { Log.v("status ","tab on position"+position);

         new ShowFullNews().execute();
      }
      });
 getUrlData(baseUrl);

 }`

`showNewsListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
 showNewsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
            Log.v("status ","tab on   position"+position);

         new ShowFullNews().execute();
      }
      });
 getUrlData(baseUrl);

 }`
```

Then also my code is crashing and not giving error just giving two warnings.

If I start a new activity in both places onTouch and post execute then my code is working but here it first show screen and then its went automatically and refresh that screen, that is not looking good. so how to avoid it. Please help me.

My working code is:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
            Log.v("status ","tab on   position"+position);

            //set bundle to send data into other activity
            b.putInt("total", 10);
            b.putInt("position",position);
            b.putStringArray("allurls", allsNewsUrls);
            b.putString("returnname", "BizTab");
            b.putString("footertext","Biz");
            b.putInt("tabid", 3);

           Intent myIntent = new Intent(BizTab.this, MainView.class);
            myIntent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            new ShowFullNews().execute();
      }
      });

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) { try { 
   Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(BizTab.this, MainView.class);

 startActivity(myIntent2);


} catch (Exception e) {
 Log.v("error","error in starting new activity");
 e.printStackTrace();
}

  }`
```

The Log generating are and  my app is closing automatically.

```
12-07 11:55:18.684: WARN/InputManagerService(72): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44067388
12-07 11:55:20.792: VERBOSE/status(419): tab on   position0
12-07 11:55:20.814: INFO/ActivityManager(72): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=org.nuvus/.MainView (has extras) }
12-07 11:55:20.872: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(419): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43ea45d8 has no id.
12-07 11:55:21.023: VERBOSE/status(419): mainView oncreate called
12-07 11:55:21.452: VERBOSE/status(419): onStartcalled
12-07 11:55:21.962: INFO/ActivityManager(72): Displayed activity org.nuvus/.MainView: 1072 ms (total 1072 ms)
12-07 11:55:22.082: INFO/AndroidRuntime(419): AndroidRuntime onExit calling exit(0)
12-07 11:55:22.173: INFO/ActivityManager(72): Process org.nuvus (pid 419) has died.
12-07 11:55:22.183: INFO/WindowManager(72): WIN DEATH: Window{43fe6f30 org.nuvus/org.nuvus.Main paused=true}
12-07 11:55:22.202: INFO/WindowManager(72): WIN DEATH: Window{440f9620 org.nuvus/org.nuvus.MainView paused=false}
12-07 11:55:22.283: INFO/UsageStats(72): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in org.nuvus
12-07 11:55:22.303: WARN/InputManagerService(72): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 419 uid 10032
```

please help me...

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(BizTab.this, MainView.class);
myIntent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Try with:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BizTab.this); <!-- or MainView.class-->
myIntent.putExtras(b);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Fixed my problem. Could you explain why it does?